# & sign in a POST var

Tags: php, ios, post

Hello I'm sending posts var to a php mysql using PDO and apache server from an iPhone but if i put an `&` sign in the content of a var it interpret it as a separator. I tried \& but it does not work. Any clue? thanks

```
   @"myID=%@&asCreatorPresentation=%@&firstName=%@&lastName=%@&phoneNumber
```

Comment: if you run the var through `urlencode()`, it will properly escape it.

Comment: okay thanks everybody :) I must wait to confirm answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to `urlencode` your POST var names and values.

For instance, `&` signs become `%26`.

Answer (score 3):

You must `urlencode` your string.

```
[NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]]
```

Comment: no, URL encoding it will not affect how you grab the data with PHP

Comment: by the way i used this with UTF8 and it does not add percent for & sign only for space and other

Comment: maybe i'll manually encode it myself then or maybe its because i use string with format